# How to configure fop2 with xivo/wazo

Tags: debian, asterisk

I have installed wazo on Debian 9 and I also installed fop2 by following [this documentation](http://documentation.wazo.community/en/stable/_downloads/fop2.pdf).

When I try to connect to the connection manager using  `/usr/local/fop2/fop2_server --test`, the the test returns "OK".

But when use it from the web interface, I get this "One moment please" screen: 
[image: Waiting]

Has anyone been able to succeed in getting fop2 to work with Wazo recently?